# Validation textbox uses integers ASP

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm trying to create a simple text box that will take a number from 10 to 500 that a user can enter. To accomplish this I'm using the following code:

```
Numbers: <asp:textbox ID="range" runat="server" ForeColor="Black"></asp:textbox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="stake"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" ControlToValidate="range" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" MinimumValue="10" MaximumValue="500" ErrorMessage="Whole number between 10 and 500 required"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

What is really confusing me however is that for some reason unless a user enters a 10 or 500, the error message appears. I'm not sure what is breaking the three lines of code and causing no numbers between 10-500 to work. Is there something that I'm missing? I'm new to ASP.net and unsure what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add the type in your `RangeValidator`

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" ControlToValidate="range" runat="server" 
ForeColor="Red" MinimumValue="10" MaximumValue="500" Type="Integer" 
ErrorMessage="Whole number between 10 and 500 required"></asp:RangeValidator>
```